# How to change input helper's class based on some condition in Ember

Tags: ember.js, htmlbars

How can the `if` condition clause be used in an input helper.

I tried:

```
{{input class="{{if errors.name "style-error"}}" }}
```

It caused building error.

the `errors.name` here is property from controller.

I reckon that it is the nested double curly braces causing the syntax error, but don't know how to achieve this conditional class declaration.

Comment: @Kitler I did know nested curly braces cannot work. I put it here to illustrate my objective.

Comment: Ah right I completely missed it when I saw your double quotes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can nest helpers using parenthesis:

```
{{input class=(if errors.name "style-error")}}
```

You should use this instead of the `xxxBinding="..."` syntax

---

You can use the `concat` helper to conditionally add multiple classes:

Conditionally add static + dynamic class:

```
{{input class=(if errors.name (concat "static-class " dynamicClass))}}
```

Conditionally add two dynamic classes:

```
{{input class=(if errors.name (concat dynamicClass1 " " dynamicClass2))}}
```

Add one class if the condition is true, another if it's false:

```
{{input class=(if errors.name "style-error" "style-success")}}
```

Add a class only when the condition is false:

```
{{input class=(unless errors.name "style-success")}}
```

Two conditions:

```
{{input class=(concat (if errors.name "name-error") " " (if errors.date "date-error"))}}
```

For more complex boolean arithmetic (e.g. and/or/not, equality and comparisons) you can use [ember-truth-helpers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-truth-helpers)

Comment: Awesome! so what if there are both static class and dynamic class, or two dynamic classes based on different conditions.

Comment: very helpful answer. however, this complexity is one of drawbacks in Ember.js.

Comment: Indeed, but these are some extreme examples. Instead of complex logic in the template, you should add a property to your component/controller

Answer (score 3):

Since `input` is an Ember helper here and not an HTML element use `classBinding` -

```
{{input classBinding="errors.name:style-error"}}
```

`classBinding` takes a space-separated list of arguments in the format of `<condition>:<class if true>:<class if false>`.  So in this case `style-error` will be applied when `errors.name` evaluates to `true` (ie the key exists on the hash).

Its the same syntax as `bind-attr`.  Also, `:<class>` works, and `<condition>::<class if false>`.  See the docs [here](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/templates/binding-element-class-names/).

Note that `classBinding` is currently supported (discussion [here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/11271)), but it is expected to be deprecated sometime before 3.0 (with appropriate deprecation warnings) with the introduction of angle bracket components.

Comment: this is not working. `errors.name` here is a property in controller.

Comment: See my edit.  If it's still not working, what version of ember are you using?

Comment: v1.13.0 with Ember-cli. it works. thanks! where does the attribute be documented? cannot find any documentation about this. Also, if this is about to be deprecated, then what is the replacement strategy?